# Add and modify value in a deep nested mixed array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, associative-array

Let's say you have an array like this:

```
$list = array(
  'name' => 'foobar',
  'id' => '12302',
  'group' => array(array(
     'name' => 'teamA',
     'members' => array(
       array(
         'ID' => 'OAHSJLASJ8888'
         'name' => 'eric',
         'fname' => 'lu',
         'age' => '22'
       ),
       array(
         'ID' => 'OKZ8JJLJYYH6'
         'name' => 'franz',
         'fname' => 'as',
         'age' => '33'
       ),
       array(
         'ID' => 'OKOIYHJKKK'
         'name' => 'Amr',
         'fname' => 'ok',
         'age' => '13'
       )
     )
  ),
  array(
     'name' => 'teamB',
     'members' => array(
       array(
         'ID' => 'FGZ9ILKA'
         'name' => 'Evan',
         'fname' => 'lu',
         'age' => '22'
       ),
       array(
         'ID' => 'KMLML2039KKK'
         'name' => 'Michel',
         'fname' => 'as',
         'age' => '33'
       ),
       array(
         'ID' => 'AAA2039KKK'
         'name' => 'Nickr',
         'fname' => 'ok',
         'age' => '13'
       )
     )
  )
 )
);
```

You want to add a value to the associative array named Amr which is the third element of the member key of the group key `$list[group][0][members][2][newKey] = B`

Using recursive `function` and `foreach`, I'm able to find anything I'm aiming at. Using `array_walk_recursive` I can also find the targeted key value and modify it.
Using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `foreach`, I can also find the element and modify it's value.

My issue is that I can not replace the modified object within the tree. I can follow the path down, but I'm not able to climb the tree back. I could maintain a index of each array I traverse and then recalculate the path to the key, but it looks culprit to me.

I can not modify the data structure, the dataset I have is as is.

Thanks for any help you could bring.

Code for **Iterator**:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($list));
      foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
          if ($key === 'ID') {
           $metas = get_relatedmeta_objects($value),true));
           //metas key should be added to the current array
          }
      }
```

**Recursive** method:

```
function searchKeyAndAdd( &$element) {
  if(is_array($element) || is_object($element)){
    foreach ( $element as &$key => $value ) {
      if ($key === "ID") {
         $metas = get_relatedmeta_objects($value);
         //metas key should be added to the current array
      } else if (is_array($value)) {
        searchObject($value);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

**array_walk_recursive** method:

```
function alterArray(&$item, $key, &$parentRec) {
      if (is_array($item) || is_object($item)) {
        searchObject($item);
      } 
      if ($key === 'ID') {
        $parentRec = json_decode(json_encode($parentRec), true);
        $parentRec['metas'] = get_field_objects($item); 
        // the current array is modified but the value does not go back to the $list initial array.
      } 
}

function searchObject( &$element, &$parent) {
    array_walk_recursive($element, 'alterArray', $element);
}
```

The data set could be anything. You do not know the key, you just know that some nested object can have `ID` key and when they do you want to add more content to this object.

Comment: Show us your current code, and then show us the array you want to create

Comment: Edited, hope you like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive function can do it, but you should use the `&` prefix on `$value` instead of `$key`:

```
function searchKeyAndAdd( &$element) {
  if(is_array($element) || is_object($element)){
    foreach ( $element as $key => &$value ) {
      if ($key === "ID") {
         $element['meta'] = get_relatedmeta_objects($value);
      } else {
        searchKeyAndAdd($value);
      } 
    }
  }
}

searchKeyAndAdd($list);
```

The other two methods offer no reference to the parent, although in the case of `array_walk_recursive` you tried it with the third argument, but there things get messy: to make it work on each recursive depth, you call `array_walk_recursive` recursively... but `array_walk_recursive` already visits all the key/value pairs recursively. So this will lead to many calls to *alterArray* with the same key/value, but with a different ancestor as third argument for each of them.

Furthermore, with this line:

```
$parentRec = json_decode(json_encode($parentRec), true);
```

... you lose the reference to the original `$parentRec`, and so any modification you make to `$parentRec` will no longer have an effect on the original array.